# Two-Sided Family Tree

Tags: html, css

I'm not an HTML/CSS expert. I need to create a bow-tie diagram and found the following. However, I need to "mirror" it so that I have entries on the left coming into the root, and then what I already have which are entries on the right stemming from the root. That is, that the root needs to have branches stemming to both the right and the left.

Alternatively, I can take a family tree, have the node in the middle and have boxes stem upwards as well as downwards. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML & CSS:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  min-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #000;
  ;
  font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 550px;
}
.branch {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
.branch:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  ;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  ;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  ;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  ;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
  display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><span class="label">Root</span>
  <div class="branch lv1">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-3</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-4</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```